# Allow only specific apps to use cell data, only when on 3G

Tags: data-connection, 3g, automation, tasker, firewall

I use Tasker to sync every 30 mins when on 3G. I'm on a limited data plan, and the only apps I use constantly are browser, a Twitter app (Echofon) and Whatsapp. Is there a way to allow only these apps when on cell data, and allow access to all on wifi, either with Tasker or otherwise?

I've seen similar questions here, but they're mostly outdated (pre ICS) and/or involve restricting access using DroidWall, which does not differentiate wifi and 3G.

Comment: Since when Droidwall does not differenciate between Wifi and 3G? It has checkboxes for both. As Droidwall is no longer continued, you might also want to check its follow-up [AFWall+ (Android Firewall)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.ukanth.ufirewall) (here the screenshots clearly show the differenciation).

Comment: @Izzy Incidentally droidwall was sold to Avast.... :\ AFWall+ has some glitchy teething problems...

Comment: Never heard anything of those! That would leave LBE as an option (careful on JellyBean -- don't install the app from the playstore on JB or you'll run into a boot-loop; check XDA instead. Pre-JB is fine from Playstore)? Works for me in this context (limiting apps to WiFi).

Comment: @Izzy: my knowledge of Droidwall was based on an old post here on Android.SE, thank you for correcting me. I'm on 4.2, and even AFWall+ seems to have issues according to comments on the Play Store page.

Comment: As I wrote, I did use neither of them yet -- so I cannot tell about issues first-hand. I use LBE from the playstore, which also offers this feature and works fine so far.

Comment: Related: [How to view network traffic requested by a specific app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/204022/218526)

Answer (score 6):

I know of no way to restrict an app to the 3G network (as opposed to 2G/4G), but there are several solutions to restrict apps to either WiFi or mobile networks (or keep/allow them from/to both). Examples include [DroidWall - Android Firewall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.droidwall.free)<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMEQw.jpg)</sup> (which you already mentioned, but which is discontinued), its successor [AFWall+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.ukanth.ufirewall)<sup>[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1s6Q.jpg)</sup>, <s>its fork [Android Firewall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jtschohl.androidfirewall)<sup>[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKD6k.jpg)</sup> (gone)</s>, and -- last but not least -- <s>[LBE Privacy Guard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lbe.security.lite)<sup>[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsTtD.png)</sup></s> (no longer updated; go [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=46695347&postcount=2010) for it's "big brother"'s English version). As below screenshots show, all four of them support separate settings per app for WiFi and mobile data respectively.

[image: DroidWall] [image: AFWall+]

[image: Android Firewall] [image: LBE]

As the comments state, some of them might have issues (e.g. do not install LBE from the playstore if your device runs Android 4.1 or higher, as this will leave you with a boot loop -- check [this XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1422479) instead). But one of them should do for you, I hope.

Comment: Confirmed. My internal data (from my [app lists at IzzyOnDroid](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists)) saw it last on 2014-08-28, so it's at least gone since October. Nothing I can do about that, sorry: it's neither listed at F-Droid, nor in the "Apps" repo at Aptoide. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Hmm, looks like LBE might be gone too.

Comment: @Seth Not really. Sadly, the international "Lite" version is (don't use on JB+ or you'll have a boot-loop). The bloated Chinese mega-pack still is available, internationalized by our friends at XDA. See [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=46695347&postcount=2010) for the English one.

Comment: A great firewall app alternative for non-rooted is  https://github.com/M66B/NetGuard, it's open-source and well maintained and has been around for a while, I use it as well you can find it on the android Playstore  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.faircode.netguard

Answer (score 1):

You can set permissions (Allowed All / Wi-Fi Only / Blocked All) on per-app basis with LostNet Firewall: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lostnet.fw.free

Comment: Please read the documentation regarding self-promotion in the [Help Center](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).