# Remove internet access for pre-installed apps that you can't disable

Tags: internet, data-connection, samsung-stellar

I don't like any of the bloat-ware that comes pre-installed with my phone. I don't understand why carriers think they're helping me by putting it on there and not letting me take it off. When they let you disable it, it is at least a step in the right direction. But certain apps can't be disabled. The worst part is that they **use up data without being able to turn it off**.

I want to disable internet access for pre-installed apps, is this possible?

Comment: It sounds like one of these previous questions is related to what you're after: [Preventing mobile data use for select apps on non-rooted phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10414/), or [Allow only specific apps to use cell data, only when on 3G](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37067/), or [Block apps from accessing the Internet on Android device](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40924/)

Answer (score 1):

With Android 4.x you can Disable carrier installed applications by going to the Settings -> Applications and select the app. You should then see "Disable" for the application.

Now, Samsung has found a way to prevent some applications to not be disabled, like their Launcher, Email client, stock browser.

You can also go to Settings -> Data usage and select the application and choose "Restrict background data". This will prevent the application from using the mobile network, but if you are on wifi, it will allow it network access.

Comment: The problem is that the ones using all the data is not disable as I disabled as much crapware as possible. I'm over wifi a lot but it's limited as well.