# Limiting only certain apps to use mobile data

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, mobile-data, background-data

Is there any way so that I can limit only one or two apps to use my mobile data in Android 4.4.2?

PS: I know about blocking background data, but I am curious about any other way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow only specific apps to use cell data, only when on 3G](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37067/allow-only-specific-apps-to-use-cell-data-only-when-on-3g)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to turn off cell data on specific apps, just uncheck the box that corresponds to connectivity and you are all set. Otherwise, install firewall apps from Play Store.